# Notifications Drawer

Tags: user-expectation, notification, feedback

We are working on a desktop app with lots of events/alerts/notifications.
Because of that, we created a 'notification drawer', similar to the this one:

[image]

My question is: **do you expect the snackbars and banners (that generate the notifications inside the drawer) to keep appearing (outside of it) when you have the drawer open?** or would you just let them know (somewhere in the drawer) that they have new notifications and they need to update the panel?

Comment: If you are going to indicate incoming notifications inside the dropdown, I think it will be better to directly refresh the list. The red dot indicating unread notifications can be retained to indicate new notifications regardless of whether the drawer is open.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the content of those notifications (does your user need to see system notifications?) I would still expect Snackbars to appear (and fade away after 7/10 seconds) because the notification drawer might be closed when the notification is triggered. User can still retrieve the communication in the drawer where it will be listed.

I would expect the Snackbar to not overlay the drawer.

If the drawer is open and a notification is triggered I would expect to see it appear in the drawer treated differently visually. If the logic of not showing the snackbar when the drawer is open is too expensive, I would still make it appear behind the drawer.

Answer (score 0):

There is very less duration user keeps drawer open. It would help if drawer is open, new notifications can hover for a short duration on upper right corner and fade away and gets added to existing opened drawer. If this is done for every notification, would be a consistent experience for user.

Comment: That's true for temporary notifications. However, if you have a banner (https://material.io/design/components/banners.html) it will persist until the user acknowledges it...